# Rails array style nested parms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, rest

So I have objects that I'm trying to pass to a json-acccepting restful interface using parms and @connection, but the source object and the target are in different formats, so I need to rename them.

So I'm trying to do something like this:

```
parms = {
  :foo => anBunchOfBars.bar[
    :barID => bar.Identifier
    :bartab => bar.finances.owed
    :barbell => bar.equipment.first
  ]
}
```

... to generate an outgoing JSON similar to the following:

```
{
   "foo": [
      {
        "barID": "Irish Pub",
        "bartab": "30 Yen",
        "barbell": "Of the ball."
      }, 
      {
        "barID": "One Gold Bar",
        "bartab": "100 cents",
        "barbell": "fry."
      }
   ]
}
```

But I can't find the proper syntax. Examples I've found seem to only cycle through a core list and leave out naming items on nested traits (or skip nested traits entirely), and I haven't seen anything that shows how to pull values from a looped item.

What's the proper syntax to format the parms value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `anBunchOfBars` is an array of bars:

```
bars = anBunchOfBars.map do |bar|
  {    
    barID: bar.Identifier
    bartab: bar.finances.owed
    barbell: bar.equipment.first
  }
end

params = { foo: bars }
```

Comment: I had been hoping there was a way rather than iterating over the whole array; but it is what it is, I suppose.